# Is the study of IQ an example of greedy reductionism?

Tags: reductionism, intelligence

Is the study of IQ an example of greedy reductionism?

> [greedy reductionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_reductionism) occurs when "in their eagerness for a bargain, in
>   their zeal to explain too much too fast, scientists and philosophers
>   ... underestimate the complexities, trying to skip whole layers or
>   levels of theory in their rush to fasten everything securely and
>   neatly to the foundation".

What good reasons are there for or against something as complex as a skill, let alone ability or all abilities, *reduces* to what is measured (however accurately) by IQ tests? Alternatively, is the study of IQ not reductionist?

I'm asking specifically about the philosophy of reductionism.

Comment: @Eff Could you convert your remarks into an answer, your perspective may be helpful to other users. References to modern literature on the status of IQ would also be helpful.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86368/discussion-on-question-by-confused-is-the-study-of-iq-an-example-of-greedy-reduc).